# Highcharts reflow does not work on class selector

Tags: jquery, class, highcharts, jquery-selectors, reflow

Has anyone tried running the High charts reflow() function on a class selector instead of an id selector?

See example where i have 2 charts with 1 button to toggle their containing div size.
I have another 2 buttons, one to reflow the charts by id, and another the reflow the charts by class.

Note the one using the class selector does not seem to reflow BOTH charts, and that it only reflows the first element using that class.

http://jsfiddle.net/deN74/1/

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div style="width: 600px">
    <div id="container1" class="needreflow" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 1em; border: 1px solid gray"></div>
    <div id="container2" class="needreflow" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 1em; border: 1px solid gray"></div>
</div>
<button id="set-div-size" class="autocompare">Toggle container size</button>
<button id="reflow-chart-byid" class="autocompare">Reflow charts by id selector</button>
<button id="reflow-chart-byclass" class="autocompare">Reflow charts by class selector</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container1').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
        }]

    });
    $('#container2').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
        }]

    });

    var wide = false;
    $('#set-div-size').click(function () {
        $('#container1').width(wide ? 400 : 500);
        $('#container2').width(wide ? 400 : 500);
        wide = !wide;
    });
    $('#reflow-chart-byid').click(function () {
        $('#container1').highcharts().reflow();
        $('#container2').highcharts().reflow();
    });
        $('#reflow-chart-byclass').click(function () {
        $('.needreflow').highcharts().reflow();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good observation, and I believe it comes down to how the `.highcharts()` function is implemented. As observed, it doesn't effect multiple elements with class-selectors, because it only works on single elements.

If you look in [the source code](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js) (lines 971-1005) at the function you can see that this is the code:

```
/**
 * Register Highcharts as a plugin in the respective framework
 */
$.fn.highcharts = function () {
    ...

    // When called without parameters or with the return argument, get a predefined chart
    if (options === UNDEFINED) {
        ret = charts[attr(this[0], 'data-highcharts-chart')];
    }

    ...
    return ret;
}
```

The return value will always be `this[0]`, which means no matter how many elements you select, it will return the first, and does not handle multiple elements at all.

The `reflow` will also only be executed once, as the `highcharts`-function doesn't return a list that the `reflow`-function can operate on. And if it did, I'm guessing the `reflow` function doesn't support multiple elements either.

One solution may be using a `.each` to iterate over each container you find with your selector, like so ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deN74/2/)):

```
$('.needreflow').each(function() { $(this).highcharts().reflow(); });
```